# How to remove easing on animation in C4?

Tags: animation, c4

I have a few lines of words (labels) that have been added to a canvas. I am animating a shape so that it moves from outside of canvas to right under one of the labels.

When I run the following code:

```
-(void)showContent {
    shapeonpage1.animationDuration = 10.0f;
    shapeonpage1.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
}
```

... the animated shape first appears to move slowly, then gradually speeds up, and slows down again when it reaches its destination.

Is there a way for my animated shape not to speed up and slow down, but move at a consistent speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to set the `animationOptions` for `shapeonpage1` to `LINEAR`.
Like so:

```
-(void)showContent {
    shapeonpage1.animationDuration = 10.0f;
    shapeonpage1.animationOptions = LINEAR;
    shapeonpage1.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
}
```

Unfortunately, there aren't many examples that show how to fully use animation options. However, you could have a look at the C4Control documentation for more info.